# How to load data from Django to a variable for a D3 graph

Tags: javascript, python, django, d3.js

I want to know how can I update a variable from a backend in Django, and update the graph I am building on the front end with D3, without refreshing the page, that is, do the update dynamically.

I managed to update the graph, but each time I change the parameters in the form in the front-end, it renders the whole page, I just want to update the data and refresh the graph in D3.

Here is my view:

```
def growth(request):
parsedData = []
if request.method == 'POST':
    year_input = request.POST.get('years')
    year_input_int = int(year_input)
    growth_data = requests.get('https://www.ons.gov.uk/economy/grossdomesticproductgdp/timeseries/ihyp/qna/data')
    # jsonList = []
    # jsonList.append(json.loads(growth_data.content))
    parsed_json = json.loads(growth_data.content)
    growthData = {}
    data_input = 'years'
    for data in parsed_json[data_input][year_input_int:]:
        growthData['date'] = data['date']
        growthData['value'] = data['value']
        growthData['year'] = data['year']
        parsedData.append(growthData.copy())
return render(request, 'dashboard/growth.html', { 'growth_json': json.dumps(parsedData) })
```

Here is my form HTML,

```
  <form method= "post" action="/indicators/growth/">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <br>
  <select type="text" name="years">
    <option value="60">2009</option>
    <option value="61">2010</option>
    <option value="62">2011</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <button type="botton">Get Data</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `return render(...)` again after doing `request.POST`.

```
def growth(request):
    template_name = 'dashboard/growth.html'
    parsedData = []
    context = {'growth_json': parsedData, 'success': False}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        ...
        for data in parsed_json[data_input][year_input_int:]:
            growthData['date'] = data['date']
            growthData['value'] = data['value']
            growthData['year'] = data['year']
            parsedData.append(growthData.copy())

        context.update({'success': True})
        return render(request, template_name, context) # here
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

and in your template;

```
{% if success %}
  {{ growth_json }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I did that and works, thanks. But how do I change the data in the graph, without refreshing the whole page?